# pKeyFIlter: NG8007: The property and event halves of the two-way binding 'ngModel' are not bound to the same target

Tags: angular, primeng

I have updated my Angular 11 project using primeng controls to Angular 12. Once done, the primeng pKeyFilter throws an error everywhere it is used. Creating a new Angular 12 project from scratch does not have this problem. Everything else appears to work fine after the upgrade. Any thoughts?

Here is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-key',
  templateUrl: './key.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./key.component.scss']
})
export class KeyComponent implements OnInit {
  public myvalue: string = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="myvalue" pKeyFilter="int"/>

<p>
  <span>{{myvalue}}</span>
</p>
```

Here is the full error

> Error:
> src/app/modules/nourishment/pages/test/key/key.component.html:1:23 -
> error NG8007: The property and event halves of the two-way binding
> 'ngModel' are not bound to the same target.
> Find more at https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works
>
> 1 <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="myvalue" pKeyFilter="int"/>
> ~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:3297:22
> 3297 export declare class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
> ~~~~~~~
> The property half of the binding is to the 'NgModel' component.
>
> node_modules/primeng/keyfilter/keyfilter.d.ts:6:22
> 6 export declare class KeyFilter implements Validator {
> ~~~~~~~~~
> The event half of the binding is to the 'KeyFilter' component.
>
> src/app/modules/nourishment/pages/test/key/key.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './key.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component KeyComponent.

I understand the basics behind the error but I can't figure out what is triggering it. I have primes InputModule and KeyFilterModule imported as well as FormsModule in the parent module. Again, this was all working prior to the upgrade. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/keyfilter

Comment: I have the same problem and I think is an incompatibility between pKeyFilter and ngModel on primeng v11.4.0+ (in 11.4.5 appears even doesn't work) ... any way It seems to be an error but functionallity appears still working ... (I'm using Angular 11)

Answer (score 12):

I just changed the order of [(ngModel)] in first and [pKeyFilter] in last

**from** :

```
<input type="text"  pInputText [pKeyFilter]="'money'" [(ngModel)]="tare" >
```

**To**:

```
<input type="text"  pInputText  [(ngModel)]="tare" [pKeyFilter]="'money'" >
```

its working good

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: I found that I needed to change the order as described, AND I had to change pKeyFilter="alphanum" to [pKeyFilter]="'alphanum'". Then it worked.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I tried to two way databind a custom property, but to allow that i had to add a event.

```
@Input() value: unknown
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<unknown>();
```

Comment: Thanks, and the name of the event must be '<input-name>Change'

Answer (score 2):

When I turned on Angular's:

```
angularCompilerOptions: strictTemplates
```

I also get this error.

Try:

```
[pKeyFilter]="'int'"
```

It's working for me

I use

```
"@angular/core": "^12.2.0", // etc...
"primeng": "^12.0.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

Had to change

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="myvalue" pKeyFilter="int"/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="myvalue" [pKeyFilter]="'int'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I opened a new issue to fix this:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10524

Answer (score 0):

I had to change 2 things: `pKeyFilter="int"` to `[pKeyFilter]="'int'"` **AND** had to move `pKeyFilter` to be before `ngModel`

Please don't ask why it works, just go with it...

️